# Python jira is not upgraded by pip

Tags: python, pip, python-jira

I am using python jira package installed using PIP in a virtual environment. Recently my script started to complain about jira package version:

```
$ ./my_script.sh
jira/client.py:282: UserWarning: You are running an outdated version of JIRA Python 1.0.3. Current version is 1.0.6.dev20160420173258. Do not file any bugs against older versions.
```

I tried upgrade using pip like:

```
$ pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir jira
    Collecting jira
Downloading jira-1.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (46kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 175kB/s
Requirement already up-to-date: requests>=2.6.0 in <...>/.virtualenvs/jira/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from jira)
Requirement already up-to-date: requests-oauthlib>=0.3.3 in <...>/.virtualenvs/jira/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from jira)
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.9.0 in <...>/.virtualenvs/jira/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from jira)
Requirement already up-to-date: requests-toolbelt in <...>/.virtualenvs/jira/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from jira)
Requirement already up-to-date: tlslite>=0.4.4 in <...>/.virtualenvs/jira/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from jira)
Requirement already up-to-date: oauthlib>=0.6.2 in <...>/.virtualenvs/jira/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.3.3->jira)
Installing collected packages: jira
Successfully installed jira-1.0.3
```

I tried to remove installed jira package and install it freshly with same result. Pip always installs only version 1.0.3 but scripts complain about newer version.

My assumption is that 1.0.6 is marked as released (the check is inside the package itself) but not published (I don´t know if this is the right word) for pip to download.

Any clue?

Regards,
JrBenito

Comment: the same is now happening with 1.0.7.devxxxxxxx. As Cory and Miles  pointed below, a workaround is possible until Jira Python team solves this once and for all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears there is a `1.0.6.dev20160420173258` version but this isn't being downloaded when using `pip install jira`. It can be installed by using the workaround found on the [issue #156](https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/issues/156) for this new version. `pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/f6/ea/2535e412ff76d85da20d2be6d1eaf9aa5de49481da94f2fe7e8830eedd35/jira-1.0.6.dev20160420173258-py2.py3-none-any.whl` Which it appears you have already commented on, so hopefully they resolve the issue permanently.

Comment: In fact this forces install of 1.0.6 but the problem is really related to python package. After install 1.0.6 as you suggested above the error continues as: [...]You are running an outdated version of JIRA Python 1.0.6. Current version is 1.0.6.dev20160420173258. [...]

Comment: It appears it is doing a string comparison within [client.py#L321](https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/blob/develop/jira/client.py#L321) and therefore, `"1.0.6.dev20160420173258" > "1.0.6"`. You could modify the [VERSION in version.py](https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/blob/develop/jira/version.py#L10) to be the same as the dev if this doesn't allow you to continue with your application. You would then need to reinstall using `python setup.py install`.

Comment: Actually, this is only an annoying warning. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue, even after specifically downloading the `1.0.6.dev20160420173258` version. When the `client.py` file gets the version information, it doesn't get the git changeset correctly and so returns `1.0.6` instead of `1.0.6.dev20160420173258`.

For now I made a workaround by hardcoding the version number pulled from `https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jira/json`

In `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jira/client.py`:

```
released_version = "1.0.6" # data['info']['version']
```

This is admittedly not a fix but lets hope it gets fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me only after changed it to

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jira/client.py:
```

with

```
released_version = "1.0.6" # data['info']['version']
```